# Excel IF Function reading non-numeric value as greater than a numeric value

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am attempting to use the formula below to calculate residuals from the slope (X1) and intercept (X2) of a regression. However, I am running into the issue that when there is a non-numeric value in X6 (e.g. N/A) the IF function is returning a '0'. In other words, N/A in being interpreted as less than a numeric value, which is misleading...

```
=IF(X6>=((X1*E6)+X2),"1","0")
```

What am I missing? I would expect a non-numeric value to return an error when using `>=`.

I have attempted to nest IF functions to get around this (variations of `=(IF(X6=N/A, "N/A",IF(X6>=((X1*E6)+X2),"1","0")`) but couldn't get it to work.

**UPDATE: And now I have tried =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(X6),X6>=(X1*E6)+X2), 1, 0) with the same result -- even when X6 has an N/A or is blank, it is still returning  a 0.
So when either condition is false, it is returning a 0 (if not a number or if less than the second condition), but i need it to only return a 0 if it is a number less than the second condition, and to return an N/A or other error if the reference cell contains text. How can I specify this?**

Plz help!

Answer (score 0):

### Assuming `N/A` is text...

Excel is doing a binary comparison. In binary terms, you can convince yourself that N/A is indeed greater than the numbers you are probably working with with a simple online converter.

---

To get around this shortcoming, make sure you are comparing numbers to numbers with `ISNUMBER`.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(X6),X6>=(X1*E6)+X2),1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I can't get this to work. As soon as I add the necessary second parenthesis before X1 [so it reads ((X1*E6)+X2)] it goes all out of wack. It needs another closing parenthesis, and if I add it after ISNUMBER(X6) is says "you've entered too many arguments for this function" and if I add it at the end it says "There's a problem with this formula." Not sure where to go from here....

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(X3),X3>=(($X$111*EZ3)+$X$112),1,0))

Comment: I can't replicate. This works find on my end. Just tested it as is

Comment: Even with the additional parenthesis before X1?  [e.g. ((X1*E6)]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got what I wanted with this:

=IF(ISNUMBER(X6),IF(X6>=(X1*E6)+X2,1,0))

It returns a FALSE if there isn't a numerical value in X6, and then the second statement returns a 0 or 1 for cells with numerical values.